# How to use “progress-bar.sh” to display the progress of operations that occur on remote servers

Tags: linux, bash

I need to integrate a progress bar to operations on remote server over SSH.

In my situation there are several loops that trigger processes on few remote servers over SSH. These processes are being triggered with `certainFunction` and take between 10 to 60 minutes (depending on many unpredictable things). As far as the processes are controlled from a main server, I’d like to display some progress bar based on timing, like percentage or bar (NOT dots or spinner), that would be indicating an overall progress.

Is this possible?

Looking for some extravagant solution I found [Édouard Lopez’s `progress-bar.sh` project](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/progress-bar.sh) to be suitable for my needs.

Here is the code for `progress-bar.sh`:

```
progress-bar() {
  local duration=${1}


    already_done() { for ((done=0; done<$elapsed; done++)); do printf "▇"; done }
    remaining() { for ((remain=$elapsed; remain<$duration; remain++)); do printf " "; done }
    percentage() { printf "| %s%%" $(( (($elapsed)*100)/($duration)*100/100 )); }
    clean_line() { printf "\r"; }

  for (( elapsed=1; elapsed<=$duration; elapsed++ )); do
      already_done; remaining; percentage
      sleep 1
      clean_line
  done
  clean_line
}
```

Can it be used for my situation? I am looking for a pure Bash solution with no additional packages being installed.

Comment: So you want to have an overall progress bar based on timing for things that take between 10 to 60 minutes depending on many *unpredictable* things, right? Does a single process (as a separate entity) know its predicted duration time or progress or anything when it runs? and can it report this to you? If not, I'm afraid you need a psychic to guess the `$duration`; especially when there are many unpredictable things. Probably the best progress indicator you can have is like "N of M tasks done".

Comment: N of M sounds very good! How can I acheive this? I do know the amount of elements in array, and catch the events of finishing the process.

Comment: What exact command(s) do you run locally to trigger these remote tasks?

Comment: All the commands (rsync, ssh, exec...) are combined into a single 'function' triggered by 'for' loop (takes IPs from the array) with 'wait' in the end. So currently there is only the last print in vein of "simultaneous upgrade launched", and then just boring time of waiting

Comment: Get number of IPs from your array and feed your functions: `progress-bar ${#arrayOfIPaddresses[@]}` and instead of `sleep` command, run your actual code

Comment: Totally disagree with your opinion. The purpose of this community to help each other, to share the ideas, to highlight mistakes. My question is about whether what I asked is possible or not, and to get the opinions, not a word about 'code for me'. I didn't even post my code :-). I respect your opinion, and if you're not alone- I probably should look for another mentoring community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a progress bar is easy; that is not your problem. You could use

```
declare -i progress
progress=1
declare -i width
width=$(tput cols)-10
declare -i pbarlength


prt_bar(){
    pbarlength=$((width*progress/100))
    echo -en "\r"
    for i in `seq $pbarlength` ; do
        echo -n '='
    done
    echo -en " $progress   "

}
```

or something like that

The main problem is to determine what your progress is. If you do try to do it by time, you will most certainly get false feeling of progress, because the process (I quote): take between 10 to 60 minutes (depending on many unpredictable things).

If it's just based on timing, you could use:

```
while [ $progress -lt 100 ] ; do
    progress=$((progress+1))
    prt_bar
    sleep 10
done
echo 
echo done
```

But if you do not have a measure of how the processes are progressing, and you are not capable of providing a realistic estimation of the actual progress, it is useless to provide a progress bar. The clock widget of your favorite window manager would provide as much relevant information.